# What preview photo formats are available?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapture, avcapturephotosettings

I'm iterating over AVCapturePhotoSettings.[availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings/1778629-availablepreviewphotopixelformat?language=objc) like this:

```
for av in availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes {
    print("Avbl preview type: \(av)")
}
```

And I get non-descriptive numbers like:

```
Avbl preview type: 875704422
Avbl preview type: 875704438
Avbl preview type: 1111970369
```

What do these actually mean? What difference will it make if I choose one instead of another? Where can I find documentation about them?